# SQL Server Tables not showing up in Logic Apps Designer using a successful on-premise connection

Tags: azure, ssms, azure-logic-apps

I am using Logic Apps Designer on Azure to move source data to a storage file and I need to connect to a database on my SQL Server. To do this, I am using an on-premise connection througha gateway. I was able to successfully connect to my SQL Server database, however, when I am using Logic Apps action, not all tables are available on Logic Apps. Is there a security/permissions/connections issue that is preventing all tables from the SQL Server database not to return to Logic Apps?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM7fm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtcZv.png)

I tried refreshing/restarting Azure and also tried connecting through with other authentications hoping more tables would return, but no luck.

Comment: What credentials are you using to connect to SQL Server? Are you logging in with the same account in both screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a new api connection to sql and try to access tables again. There might be issue with connecting to db.

One of the alternative approaches to get row from sql db is using execute query action in logic app.
[image]
As shown in above picture, **Execute a SQL query (V2)** action is used to query table and retrieve records based on condition.

Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/109279/tables-not-populating-in-the-tables-dropdown-durin)